# Special characters on input come in as %nn

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have an HTML FORM requesting the name of a movie to search for, and a JavaScript function which takes that name passed as a query parameter (after a ?) on a reinvocation of the page URL and compares it against a database (read with AJAX).  The problem is that special characters are being translated on input to **%nn**, so they don't match the names in the database.  For example, when I read the user input of "airplane!" with "title = window.location.search" I receive "airplane%21".  How can I defeat or correct this behavior, or am I going to have to translate every %nn in my JavaScript routine?  Thank you.
(Page reference:  https://acb.org/adp/findavideo.html)

Arggh!  Not 2 seconds after I posted this, someone sent me an answer offline:  "title = decodeURIComponent(title)" does the trick.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: "*a JavaScript function which takes that name passed as a query parameter (after a ?) on a reinvocation of the page URL*" - please [edit] your question to include the code of that function.

Comment: That's URL encoding. Generally server-side frameworks automatically decode that for you.

Comment: It's called [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), and you will want to use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try decode the value before use it, for example:

```
decodeURIComponent('%21'); // "!"
```